# Understanding syslog conf - targeting specific types / tags of logs

Tags: logging, syslog

I'm combining log files from several docker containers on my host and sending them a remote logging service. I'm just redirecting the output to logger and tagging it:

```
docker-compose logs 2>&1 | logger -t deviant
```

This is easily configurable via:

```
*.*  @remote_service:remote_port
```

However, `*.*` matches every kind of logs from my host machine, when I only want to send the redirected logs to the remote service.

Here's an example of a log I want to capture:

```
Apr 08 08:55:04 calvin.local deviant:  proxy_1 | 192.168.59.3 - - [08/Apr/2015:15:55:04 +0000] "stuff here"
```

Notice it contains `calvin.local deviant`

The ones containing `deviant` are the only ones I want. I've tried to specify which log entries like this:

`*deviant*`

...and restarted logging...but I still see all entries (not just ones tagged `deviant`) in my remote logs. Why?

Answer (score 2):

In `syslog.conf` you can only assign an action according to a given facility and level of the message.

The tag specified by `logger -t [tag]` cannot be used for identifying the message by syslog. However you could use `-p [facility.level]'` option of `logger` to set custom facility and level, for example:

```
logger -t deviant -p local3.info
```

Then in syslog.conf you could catch and redirect these messages:

```
local3.info  @remote_service:remote_port
```

Try to find a facility that is not used by any other service. Good choice would be one of `local0` to `local7`.

When you specify a level, like `info`, by default it means the minimum level that will be matched by the rule.

Read more:

- [man logger](http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger)
- [man syslog.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog.conf)